# Firebase Firestore and Google Maps Custom Marker only showing one marker

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use the plugin [Custom Marker](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_marker) to show on google maps, I got it close to working but it's only showing one marker from my model when I expect it to show all of them. Why is firestore only showing the one marker, how do I get the full list to show all of the markers instead of just one?

Edit 1: Removed old create marker function, that worked to make normal google map markers. Now all that's left is functioning code, it just only shows one marker instead of the entire list.

Edit 2: After reviewing the initial suggestion below I realize I'm getting a similar error message as to their suggestion.

Edit 3: Working code is at the bottom per suggestion by @Denzel

Unhandled Exception: setState() callback argument returned a Future.
E/flutter (31835): The setState() method on _HomePageState#73fe9 was called with a closure or method that returned a Future. Maybe it is marked as "async".
E/flutter (31835): Instead of performing asynchronous work inside a call to setState(), first execute the work (without updating the widget state), and then synchronously update the state inside a call to setState().

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:custom_marker/marker_icon.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../models/marker_collect_model.dart';

class CustomMarkies extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<CustomMarkies> {
  Set<Marker> list = <Marker>{};
  List<String> listDocuments = [];

  Future<void> readDataFromFirebase() async {
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionReference =
    firestore.collection('2022TABR');
    collectionReference.snapshots().listen((event) {
      List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshots = event.docs;
      for (var map in snapshots) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data =
        map.data() as Map<String, dynamic>; // add this line
        MarkerCollectModel model =
        MarkerCollectModel.fromMap(data); // use data here
        String nameDocument = map.id;
        listDocuments.add(nameDocument);
        setState(() async {
          Random random = Random();
          int i = random.nextInt(10000);
          String idString = 'id$i';
          list.add(Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(idString),
            icon: await MarkerIcon.downloadResizePicture(
                url: model.urlavatar!, imageSize: 250),
            position: LatLng(model.lat!, model.lng!),
          );
        });
      }
    });
  }
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(45.4279, -123.6880), zoom: 3),
        markers: list,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        label: FittedBox(child: Text('Add Markers')),
        onPressed: () async {
          readDataFromFirebase();
          list.toSet();
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}
```

working code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:custom_marker/marker_icon.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../models/marker_collect_model.dart';

class CustomMarkies extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<CustomMarkies> {
  Set<Marker> list = <Marker>{};
  List<String> listDocuments = [];

  Future<void> readDataFromFirebase() async {
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionReference =
    firestore.collection('2022TABR');
    collectionReference.snapshots().listen((event) async {
      List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshots = event.docs;
      for (var map in snapshots) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data =
        map.data() as Map<String, dynamic>; // add this line
        MarkerCollectModel model =
        MarkerCollectModel.fromMap(data); // use data here
        String nameDocument = map.id;
        listDocuments.add(nameDocument);
          list.add(Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(nameDocument),
            icon: await MarkerIcon.downloadResizePicture(
                url: model.urlavatar!, imageSize: 250),
            position: LatLng(model.lat!, model.lng!),
          ));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(45.4279, -123.6880), zoom: 3),
        markers: list,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        label: FittedBox(child: Text('Add Markers')),
        onPressed: () async {
          readDataFromFirebase();
          list.toSet();
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You put the marker `list.add` in `setState`, it could easily sit in the function.

Comment: It's my understanding that the custom marker plugin requires it to happen as async, but when I remove the setState and the await on the list.add I get the following error |||| The argument type 'Future<BitmapDescriptor>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BitmapDescriptor'.   I understand the function is already marked async, so not sure where to go from here. Thanks for your suggestion though, any other thoughts?

Comment: Okay and now I additionally realize I've been getting a very similar error message as to what you are describing, though I don't completely understand how to make it happy. I've updated my post with an edit showing the error.

Comment: the function is already asynchronous, so you don't need to make setState asynchronous it's wrong.

Comment: I mostly understand why I was confused and stuck in a loop. When I removed the async from the setState, the await MarkerIcon wants to correct the error but putting the await back in setState. So like you said, remove the setState and just execute in the function. That still caused the await MarkerIcon to want to add in async, so I allowed it to add the async and it popped up "collectionReference.snapshots().listen((event) async " so I still for some reason need two async's in my function which is fine by me if it all works. Feel free to provide it as an answer and I will gladly upvote. thx

Comment: Please share your updated code

Comment: Okay I added it at the bottom, thanks again.

Comment: Thanks you alerted me to something I overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    class CustomMarkies extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    
    class _HomePageState extends State<CustomMarkies> {
      Set<Marker> list = <Marker>{};
      List<String> listDocuments = [];
    
      /// This [async] here covers for everything within the function,
      /// You can use [await] anywhere you want to
      /// [collectionReference.snapshots()] returns a [Stream], so you [listen] to it
      /// There's no need for [await] because [Stream] handles real-time data
      /// In essence, it would update all it's [listeners] about the new change and this change will take effect in your UI
      Future<void> readDataFromFirebase() async {
        FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
        CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionReference =
            firestore.collection('2022TABR');
        collectionReference.snapshots().listen((event) {
          for (var map in snapshots) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
            map.data() as Map<String, dynamic>; // add this line
            MarkerCollectModel model =
            MarkerCollectModel.fromMap(data); // use data here
            String nameDocument = map.id;
            listDocuments.add(nameDocument);
              list.add(Marker(
                markerId: MarkerId(nameDocument),
                icon: await MarkerIcon.downloadResizePicture(
                    url: model.urlavatar!, imageSize: 250),
                position: LatLng(model.lat!, model.lng!),
              ));
          }
        });
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition:
                CameraPosition(target: LatLng(45.4279, -123.6880), zoom: 3),
            markers: list,
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
            label: FittedBox(child: Text('Add Markers')),
            onPressed: () async {
// you have to `await readDataFromFirebase()` because it is a future.
              await readDataFromFirebase();
              list.toSet();
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
          floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        );
      }
    }
```

I put the comments to explain further what I meant